# Proportional fontsize on different screen resolutions - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms project, im using named size for my labels like this :

```
new Setter { Property = Label.FontSizeProperty, Value = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)) },
```

My problem is depending on which resolution the device is, the fontsize is not rendered proportionnaly.

Here is what is rendered on my **emulator** :

[image]

And this on my **device** :

[image]

If the size of the text on my emulator is good, it is way too small on my device and this is what i try to avoid.

I know there is lot of question about fontsize, but never found an answer about this... Did i missed something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnaly got the problem.

In the settings, fontsizes were different between my device and the emulator.
My device was setted up on tiny fontsize while my emulator wad setted up on normal fontsize.

That explain the huge difference between them !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use normal `FontSize` ? It should scale automatically depending on device size:

```
FontSize="20"
```

Your definition of medium text size may be different depending on UI `NamedSize.Medium`, You'll always loose control if you let the device decide what is small and what is large

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly the problem is still the same. By using FontSize="20", the text is bigger on my device, but wrap on my emulator because it takes too much space now... Is it impossible to have the exact same result on every resolution ?